# Adding Time passed part

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I'm wanting to do is figure out where I should place a section of code that it needs to check to see if the max login attempts are attempted then it'll check to see if 10 minutes has gone but that way the user can attempt to login again. Not sure how this logic should be added.

```
function submit()
{
    // Sets validation rules for the login form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('remember', 'Remember me', 'integer');

    // Checks to see if login form was submitted properly
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === false)
    {
        $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!');  
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_null($userData = $this->usersmodel->getUserByUsername($this->input->post('username'))))
        {
            // Username was not found in the database
            $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Incorrect username and password combination!');  
        }
        else
        {
            // Checks to see if user has exceeded max login attempts
            if ($this->auth->isMaxLoginAttemptsExceeded($userData->userID))
            {

                // Max was exceeded and sends email to account holder
                $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Your account is currently locked, we appologize for the inconvienence. You must wait 10 minutes before you can login again! An email was sent to the owner of this account!');  
                $userData = array('userID' => $userData->userID, 'firstName' => $userData->firstName, 'lastName' => $userData->lastName, 'email' => $userData->email, 'username' => $userData->username);
                $this->auth->sendEmail($this->config->item('defaultTemplate'), 'maxlogins', 'KOW Manager Account Locked', $userData);  
            }
            else
            {
                // Matches user's status for validity
                switch($userData->usersStatusesID)
                {
                    // Registered not validated
                    case 1:
                        $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Sorry you must verify your account before logging in!');  
                        break;
                    // Account suspended
                    case 3:  
                        $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Your account has been suspended!');  
                        break;
                    // Account Banned
                    case 4:
                        $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Your account is currently banned!');  
                        break;
                    // Account Deleted
                    case 5:  
                        $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Your account has been deleted!');  
                        break;
                    // Registered and validated
                    default:
                        // Checks to see if login was successful
                        if ($this->auth->login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'), $this->input->post('remember')))
                        {
                            // Login was successful
                            $outputArray = array('success' => 'Yes', 'message' => 'Sending to control panel!');    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Login failed
                            $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Incorrect username and password combination!');  
                        } 
                }
            }

        }
    }
    echo json_encode($outputArray);      
}

/**
* Check if login attempts exceeded max login attempts
*
* @param       integer
* @return      bool
*/
function isMaxLoginAttemptsExceeded($userID)
{
    $this->ci->load->model('users/usersmodel');
    $loginAttempts = $this->ci->usersmodel->getLoginAttemptsNum($this->ci->input->ip_address(), $userID);
    if ($loginAttempts >= 5)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get number of attempts to login occured from given IP-address or username
 *
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  integer
 */
function getLoginAttemptsNum($ipAddress, $userID)
{
    $this->db->where('ipAddress', $ipAddress);
    $this->db->or_where('userID', $userID);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->usersLoginsAttempts);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $query->num_rows;          
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }        
}

Fields: id, userID, ipAddress, datetime
```

Everytime the user makes an incorrect login it adds another row to the field which stores it by each 5 of either the ipAddress or userID. So it needs to look at the last datetime since it only stores the last 5.

Comment: where you record the number of login attempts, why don't you also add a timestamp of attempt and then you can query that?

Comment: I don't have that in my code.

Comment: Adding the database field is easy, then just add the methods into the user/auth code.

Comment: Please, paste here also the code of the method `$this->auth->isMaxLoginAttemptsExceeded($userID)`. This should be done within this method...

Comment: I have a log of all login attempts in my DB, then as a part of the auth process I just check the number of attempts for that user within the last X minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first choice is whether to lock the user out if:

- 5 invalid attempts have been made from the computer, any username (more likely to catch hackers)
- 5 invalid attempts have been made from the same valid username (more likely to catch users sho know a username and don't know the password).

The method you have set up is the scond of these (judging by your function isMaxLoginAttemptsExceeded($userData->userID)) )

So, based on that:

Stage 1:

Add 3 fields to the user's database: "invalid_login_count", "last_invalid"attempt" and "locked_out_until"

Stage 1:

Around the line "// Login failed" you need to record the fact an invalid attempt was made. Increment "invalid_login_count" and store in DB, set "last_invalid_attempt" to now. If "invalid_login_count" = 5, then also update "locked_out_until" to time + 5 minutes.

Stage 2:

Around the line "// Login was successful " clear the values of "invalid_login_count", "last_invalid_attempt" and "locked_out_until" (i.e. reset)

Stage 3:

If "last_invalid_attempt" has a value, and it's less than 5 minutes ago, then clear the value in "locked_out_until", "last_invalid_attempt" and "invalid_login_count". Do this as soon as you get the user details, whether invalid or now.

Stage 4:

Your $this->auth->isMaxLoginAttemptsExceeded($userData->userID) function should look at the "locked_out_until" value, and if > now, then they are locked out.

Note: this means the user can't enter 5 invalid attempts with < 5 minute gap between each one. It's not perfectly what you asked for (5 attempts in 5 minutes), but the logic of storing the times for all latest attempts and only including the last 5 minutes worth is a little harder - so I'm keeping it simple.

---

Note that I'd actually suggest locking out by IP address, which is slightly different logic as you need to have a specific table for counting attempts and locking out by IP, and you also need to update in two places (if username not found, or if password invalid) and you should throw the user out if the IP is locked before even checking if the username is valid. Otherwise, it's the same logic.